# PHP Largest Possible Integer Constant

Tags: php, integer

Was reading the PHP manual on integer overflow in the manual and was wondering: is there a PHP pre-defined constant for the current largest integer value possible? Something equivalent to the JavaScript `Number.MAX_VALUE` constant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

```
PHP_INT_MAX (integer)
    Available since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

`PHP_INT_MAX` according to [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Please note that the actual max value depends on whether PHP is compiled for 32bit or 64bit.

Also, you can use `PHP_INT_SIZE` to get the size of the integer.

Answer (score 1):

The [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) contant contains the largest possible integer (in PHP 4.4.0/5.0.5 and newer).

On 32-bit system, this would normally be `2147483647` (2.1 * 10<sup>9</sup>). On a 64-bit system, it would usually be `9223372036854775807` (9.2 * 10<sup>18</sup>).

Comment: It is not dependent upon the system.  It's dependent upon the compilation of PHP (You can install a 32 bit version of PHP on a 64 bit machine, and you'll only get a 32 bit int.  But the reverse won't work - 64 bit install on a 32 bit machine).  You need a 64 bit processor, 64 bit OS and 64 bit install of PHP...

Comment: Actually, this doesnt return the correct value, it will return 8(!) on most systems!